# Executing PsExec64.exe from Poweshell throwing "Cannot process the XML from the 'Error' stream"

Tags: powershell, psexec

From my PowerShell script I am executing `PSExec64.exe` with below parameters.

```
$CommandToExecute = "& >\PsExec64.exe -accepteula -nobanner -s powershell -Command {Another_Power_Shell_Script Arguments_To_Script}"

Invoke-Expression -Command:$CommandToExecute
```

After this I am getting below error in log file:

```
PsExec64.exe : Cannot process the XML from the 'Error' stream of
'<<Script_Path>>\PsExec64.exe': Data at the root level is  invalid.
Line 1, position 830. At line:1 char:1
+ & <<Script_Path>>\PsExec64.exe -accepteula -nobanner -s powershell -Command  { ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SyntaxError: (<<Script_Path>>\PsExec64.exe:String) [], XmlException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ProcessStreamReader_CliXmlError
```

Any inputs?

Comment: Is there a reason that `Invoke-Command` cannot be used?

Comment: I have used Invoke-Expression -Command:<<Above Command>>

Comment: What's the full command?  Does it generate an error without psexec?

Comment: I think using `Start-Process` could work. So it would look like this `Start-Process -FilePath $PathToPsExec -ArgumentList "command"`